# How to send email/SMS notifications via AWS for Todo App?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I was just wondering what would be the best way to send a reminder notification for a task that has a due date coming up using AWS services, I would prefer to send an email / sms what ever would be easier.
I'm currently using cognit for user signup and I have access to the email address here.

Thanks!

I had a look at SNS services but given that this is in a sandbox environment I won't be able to send emails to the users in my app that aren't verified. Do I have to move out of sandbox or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like using SNS to send emails for your use-case is not a good choice. You won't be able to fully customize it (no HTML support), the sender will be an AWS email and your users will need to confirm the subscription to the SNS topic.

[AWS SES](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/dg/Welcome.html) is the service you should use for sending emails to your users.

Comment: Hey, so as long as I verify my domain will I be able to send emails to my users on the app who are not verified on SNS? That's what at least the docs says. In that case I don't have to manually verify each users that's on the application.